# BufferedReader readLine() blocks

Tags: java, sockets, bufferedreader

When receiving data using readLine(), even though I put a "\n" at the end of the message
using the .flush when sending the message, the while loop that reads my message still blocks.
Only when closing the socket connection, it leaves the loop.

Here's the client code :

```
bos = new BufferedOutputStream(socket.
            getOutputStream());
bis = new BufferedInputStream(socket.
            getInputStream());
osw = new OutputStreamWriter(bos, "UTF-8");
osw.write(REG_CMD + "\n");
osw.flush();

isr = new InputStreamReader(bis, "UTF-8");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

String response = "";
String line;

while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
   response += line;
}
```

and the server's code:

```
BufferedInputStream is;
BufferedOutputStream os;

is = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
os = new BufferedOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());

isr = new InputStreamReader(is);

String query= "";
String line;

while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
   query+= line;
}

String response = executeMyQuery(query);
osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8");

osw.write(returnCode + "\n");
osw.flush();
```

My code blocks at the server while loop.
Thanks.

Comment: Put your code in try/catch block and close the streams/connection in finally block.

Comment: This doesn't seem to have a question in it. Do you want to know why this behaviour occurs? How to prevent it?

Comment: If you want to read only one line why using while loop?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The BufferedReader will keep on reading the input until it reaches the end (end of file or stream or source etc). In this case, the 'end' is the closing of the socket. So as long as the Socket connection is open, your loop will run, and the BufferedReader will just wait for more input, looping each time a '\n' is reached.

Comment: mmm I didn't think that end was the closing of the socket. Thanks. Now that I look at it, I misread the doc!

Comment: The doc is rather ambiguous when it comes to the eof for non-file streams.

Comment: It is the OP's loop that keeps reading till EOS, not the BufferedReader.

Comment: So it the connection is open but no lines are in the buffer, will it still loop?

Comment: @the_prole - the loop will continue... sort of. It won't exit the loop, but the `br.readLine()` call will block until a new line is available

Answer (score 13):

I tried a lot of solutions but the only one not blocking the execution was the following:

```
BufferedReader inStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(yourInputStream));
String line;
while(inStream.ready() && (line = inStream.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

The `inStream.ready()` returns false if the next `readLine()` call will block the execution.

Comment: You saved my month. I just needed to invert `inStream.ready()` and `(line = inStream.readLine()) != null`
My InputStream is obtained from a java.lang.Process

Comment: @LennoardSilva Yes mine also was obtained from  `java.lang.Process` so you would not know when there is nothing to read anymore using other methods.

Answer (score 3):

This is because of the condition in the while-loop: `while((line = br.readLine()) != null)`

you read a line on every iteration and leve the loop if readLine returns `null`.

readLine returns only null, if eof is reached (= socked is closed) and returns a String if a '\n' is read.

if you want to exit the loop on readLine, you can omit the whole while-loop und just do:

`line = br.readLine()`

Answer (score 1):

This happens because the InputStream is not ready to be red, so it blocks on in.readLine() .
Please try this :

```
boolean exitCondition= false;

while(!exitCondition){
    if(in.ready()){
        if((line=in.readLine())!=null){
            // do whatever you like with the line
        }
    }
}
```

Of course you have to control the exitCondition .

An other option can be the use of nio package, which allows asynchronised (not blocking) reading but it depend on your need.

Answer (score 1):

It'd be better avoid using `readline()`. This method is dangerous for network communications because some servers don't return `LF/CR` symbols and your code will be stuck. When you read from a file it isn't critical because you will reach end of the file anyway and stream will be closed.

```
public String readResponse(InputStream inStreamFromServer, int timeout) throws Exception {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inStreamFromServer, Charsets.UTF_8));
    char[] buffer = new char[8092];
    boolean timeoutNotExceeded;
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    final long startTime = System.nanoTime();
    while ((timeoutNotExceeded = (TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMillis(System.nanoTime() - startTime) < timeout))) {
        if (reader.ready()) {
            int charsRead = reader.read(buffer);
            if (charsRead == -1) {
                break;
            }
            result.append(buffer, 0, charsRead);
        } else {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(timeout / 200);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                LOG.error("InterruptedException ex=", ex);
            }
        }
    }
    if (!timeoutNotExceeded) throw new SocketTimeoutException("Command timeout limit was exceeded: " + timeout);

    return result.toString();
}
```

It has a timeout and you can interrupt communication if it take a lot of time

Comment: You have to make sure of the protocol that you are using. Most protocols specify their end-of-line behavior.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get what's in the socket without being forced to close it simply use ObjectInputStream and ObjectOutputStream ..

***Example:***

```
ObjectInputStream ois;
ObjectOutputStream oos;

ois = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream());

String dataIn = ois.readUTF(); //or dataIn = (String)ois.readObject();

oos = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
oos.writeUtf("some message"); //or use oos.writeObject("some message");
oos.flush();

.....
```

Answer (score 0):

readline() and read() will be blocked while socket doesn't close. So you should close socket:

```
Socket.shutdownInput();//after reader
Socket.shutdownOutput();//after wirite
```

rather than Socket.close();