# Java while(true) loop executes only once inside thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to implement a simple client-server application in Java.

Here is the code:

Client.java

```
public class Client implements Runnable {
    private String hostName;
    private int portNumber;
    private String message;

    private Socket socket;
    private PrintWriter writer;
    private BufferedReader reader;

    public Client(String hostName, int portNumber, String message) {
        this.hostName = hostName;
        this.portNumber = portNumber;
        this.message = message;
    }

    public void connect() {
        try {
            socket = new Socket(hostName, portNumber);
            writer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

            writer.println(message);
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            System.err.println("Could not resolve the host name '" + hostName + "'.");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Could not get the I/O for the connection to '" + hostName + "'.");
        }
    }

    private void listenForMessages() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                System.out.println("In loop!");
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(line);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        connect();
        listenForMessages();
    }
}
```

Server.java

```
public class Server implements Runnable {
    private int portNumber;
    private String message;

    private ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private Socket clientSocket;
    private PrintWriter writer;
    private BufferedReader reader;

    public Server(int portNumber, String message) {
        this.portNumber = portNumber;
        this.message = message;
    }

    private void listen() {
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portNumber);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        while (true) {
            try {
                clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                writer = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(line);
                }

                writer.println(message);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println(e.getMessage());
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        listen();
    }
}
```

And this is the main class:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Client client = new Client("localhost", 4444, "Hello from client!");
        Server server = new Server(4444, "Hello from server!");

        Thread serverThread = new Thread(server);
        serverThread.start();

        Thread clientThread = new Thread(client);
        clientThread.start();
    }
}
```

The logic of the code is simple: both the client and the server are waiting for messages inside a `while(true)` loop.

The `while` loop inside the server's `listen` method executes just fine. However, inside the `listenForMessages` method, the loop seems to be executed only once. I only see one "In loop" printed on the screen.

Can you figure out what the problem is?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you use debugger?

Comment: Well, I'm using a plain text editor and I don't know how to use the debugger from the command line.

Comment: Side note: and you are sure that you don't overlook any of your exceptions? You see, your code is just **printing** on exceptions; but then it just tries to continue what it is doing. Consider just **failing** on exceptions!

Comment: I'm guessiing that readLine is blocking your thread.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15521352/bufferedreader-readline-blocks

Comment: readLine only returns null when the socket is closed..

Comment: please add the expected output

Comment: I expect the program to output: "Helloe from the client!", "Hello from the server!" and then lots of "In loop", however not in this order.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> However, inside the `listenForMessages` method, the loop seems to be
>   executed only once. I only see one "In loop" printed on the screen.

Actually it is not because the loop is executed only once it is simply because `reader.readLine()` will make the current thread wait until it receives an entire line and here if you check the code of the `Server`, it reads first and it reads in an infinite loop as `reader.readLine()` will only return `null` at the end of the stream so when the socket will be closed in this case.

If you want to implement some kind of ping-pong between the client and the server, simply read then write on one side and write and read and the other side as next:

**`Client` code:**

```
public void connect() {
    try {
        socket = new Socket(hostName, portNumber);
        writer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        System.err.println("Could not resolve the host name '" + hostName + "'.");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println(
            "Could not get the I/O for the connection to '" + hostName + "'."
        );
    }
}

private void listenForMessages() {
    while (true) {
        try {
            System.out.println("In loop!");
            // Write the message for the server
            writer.println(message);
            // Read the message from the server
            System.out.println(reader.readLine());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

**`Server` code:**

```
while (true) {
    try {
        clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
        writer = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

        while (true) {
            // Read the message from the client
            System.out.println(reader.readLine());
            // Write the message for the client
            writer.println(message);
        }


    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        break;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
In loop!
Hello from client!
Hello from server!
In loop!
Hello from client!
Hello from server!
...
```