# out.println(); not working Java SocketServer

Tags: java, serversocket, println

I'm trying to send a message to the server through a client, but I do not see the message on the Server. It shows it's connecting properly. I think the issue has something to do with this, in the Client class but I'm not too sure. Please let me know if anyone has a solution.

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String send = reader.readLine();
out.println(send);
out.flush();
```

This is the client class:

```
package com.evolution.client;

import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Client {
   private Socket client;
   private PrintWriter out;
   private BufferedReader in;

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Client client = new Client();
       client.startConnection("localhost", 325);
   }
   public void startConnection(String ip, int port) {
       try {
           client = new Socket(ip, port);
       out = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
       in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
       System.out.println("Connected");
       out.println("Connection started from, " + client.getLocalAddress());
       out.flush();
       while (true) {
           String recieve = in.readLine();
           System.out.println(recieve);

           BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
           String send = reader.readLine();
           out.println(send);
           out.flush();
       }
            } catch (Exception e) {
               System.out.println(e);
        }
   }

   public void stopConnection() {
       try {
       in.close();
       out.close();
       client.close();
    }
       catch (Exception e) {

        }
}   
}
```

This is the server class file:

```
package com.evolution.server;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Server {
private int port = 325;
private ServerSocket server;
private Socket client;
private PrintWriter out;
private BufferedReader in;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Server server = new Server();
    System.out.println("Start Up!");
    server.start(server.port);
}

public void start(int port) throws IOException  {
    server = new ServerSocket(port);
    try {
        while (true) { //always runs unless break;
            client = server.accept();
               out = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
                in = new BufferedReader(new 
InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
                //out - send output 

                String inputLine;
                while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    if (inputLine.equalsIgnoreCase("shutdown"))
                        stop();
                    System.out.println(inputLine);
                }
        }
    }   
    finally { //runs no matter what after try {}
        server.close();
            }
    }
public void stop() {
    try {
        in.close();
        out.close();
        client.close();
        server.close();
        System.exit(0);
    }
   catch (Exception e) {  
   }
}
}
```

If you have any possible solutions please let me know.

Comment: Your stop() method will skip all remaining steps on first exception. You should wrap each .close() call in its own try..catch block, or write a function to close InputStream/OutputStream/Socket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line
String recieve = in.readLine();
on the client side will block ([BufferedReader readLine() blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15521352/bufferedreader-readline-blocks)).
Since the server isn't sending more lines, your code is stuck there.

Removing this line allows you to send messages from the client to the server.